# Site works perfectly on localhost, but not on server

Tags: php, apache2

I have weird situation.

I'm using this piece of code to logout the user from the site:

```
case 'exit':
    setcookie("hash", "", time() - 3600, '/');
    header('Location: /main');
    exit();
    break;
```

Exactly the same code is used on localhost, only difference is that on the server it won't logout. Just goes to the `/main` page and that's it. User stays logged in, but it perfectly works on localhost.

Comment: Have you checked the cookie is created successfully or not? Any error generated (check error log)?

Comment: What logging/debugging have you done so far?  "It doesn't work" isn't very helpful as a diagnostic tool.

Comment: This is the problem, there is no error or anything so I have no clue why it's caused on the hosting.

Comment: and yes, the cookie just stays there.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem aswell, I found out cookies and sessions are required by most webservices to be the VERY first line of the file. Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent.

More about headers: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Well by looking at my code it seems I'm doing it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You should give complete route on the server.
    //example
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/login");

Comment: How that could be the issue? Issue is that it's not changing the cookie on the server.